# MacOS Catalina gives errors when trying to compile example file from Boost Tutorial in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, boost

I have been trying to get started with Boost development on my Macbook, which has MacOS Catalina(OSX 10.15). The following is the link to the file, example.cpp on the Boost Getting Started on Unix Variants page:

Link: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#boost-root-directory

I'll also provide the code directly here:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

On compiling this on terminal, I get the following errors:

```
In file included from example1.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/sharvankumar/boost_1_71_0/boost/lambda/lambda.hpp:23:
In file included from /Users/sharvankumar/boost_1_71_0/boost/lambda/detail/operator_return_type_traits.hpp:24:
In file included from /Users/sharvankumar/boost_1_71_0/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:98:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/complex:246:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:313:9: error: 
      no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace
using ::signbit;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:314:9: error: 
      no member named 'fpclassify' in the global namespace
using ::fpclassify;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:315:9: error: 
      no member named 'isfinite' in the global namespace; did you mean 'finite'?
using ::isfinite;
      ~~^
/usr/local/include/math.h:749:12: note: 'finite' declared here
extern int finite(double)
           ^
In file included from example1.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/sharvankumar/boost_1_71_0/boost/lambda/lambda.hpp:23:
In file included from /Users/sharvankumar/boost_1_71_0/boost/lambda/detail/operator_return_type_traits.hpp:24:
In file included from /Users/sharvankumar/boost_1_71_0/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:98:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/complex:246:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:316:9: error: 
      no member named 'isinf' in the global namespace
using ::isinf;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:317:9: error: 
      no member named 'isnan' in the global namespace
using ::isnan;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:318:9: error: 
      no member named 'isnormal' in the global namespace
using ::isnormal;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:319:7: error: 
      no member named 'isgreater' in the global namespace; did you mean '::std::greater'?
using ::isgreater;
      ^~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:720:29: note: 
      '::std::greater' declared here
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS greater : binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
                            ^
In file included from example1.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/sharvankumar/boost_1_71_0/boost/lambda/lambda.hpp:23:
In file included from /Users/sharvankumar/boost_1_71_0/boost/lambda/detail/operator_return_type_traits.hpp:24:
In file included from /Users/sharvankumar/boost_1_71_0/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:98:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/complex:246:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:320:7: error: 
      no member named 'isgreaterequal' in the global namespace; did you mean '::std::greater_equal'?
using ::isgreaterequal;
      ^~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:749:29: note: 
      '::std::greater_equal' declared here
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS greater_equal : binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
                            ^
In file included from example1.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/sharvankumar/boost_1_71_0/boost/lambda/lambda.hpp:23:
In file included from /Users/sharvankumar/boost_1_71_0/boost/lambda/detail/operator_return_type_traits.hpp:24:
In file included from /Users/sharvankumar/boost_1_71_0/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:98:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/complex:246:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:321:9: error: 
      no member named 'isless' in the global namespace
using ::isless;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:322:9: error: 
      no member named 'islessequal' in the global namespace
using ::islessequal;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:323:9: error: 
      no member named 'islessgreater' in the global namespace
using ::islessgreater;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:324:9: error: 
      no member named 'isunordered' in the global namespace
using ::isunordered;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:325:9: error: 
      no member named 'isunordered' in the global namespace
using ::isunordered;
      ~~^
13 errors generated.
```

Now after a lot of Googling, reading posts on StackOverflow, and on the Apple Developers Forum, I came to the conclusion that there is some problem with the cmath and math.h header files in Xcode, which is causing this problem. Up to OSX 10.14, there was a fix for this, which was to install the package macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg, which would install the required headers in the base system. But from Catalina onwards, they've removed this package.

Now, until Apple provides a workaround for this, I was wondering if I could get any help that is Boost specific? The only other option is to downgrade my MacOS version, but I'm looking for an easier option. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can tell you that this has nothing to do with Boost so there won't be anything "Boost specific". I do know how to fix this, because I had to do it a few weeks ago, but I'll need to remember...

Comment: It would help if you explained how you're building this. Command-line? Or from the IDE? Using the built-in build system or using CMake?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I'm using the command line

Comment: Please, **be specific**. Not just "I'm using the command line". Give the **exact steps**. The **actual text**. Pretend that computers are complicated and that I can't see your screen from here.

Comment: @Botje yes it does!! Thanks a ton!